# $D\subset\hat{C}$ is a domain of riemann sphere $\hat{C}$. Then $Aut(D)\subset Aut(\hat{C})$?

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, automorphism-group

It is likely that this is a dumb question.

$D\subset\hat{C}$ is a domain of riemann sphere $\hat{C}$(i.e. it is connected and open). Then $Aut(D)\cong H,H\subset Aut(\hat{C})$ where $H$ is a subgroup of $Aut(\hat{C})$.

Q1. It is obviously true for $D=\Delta(1)$ unit disk and any simply connected domain is diffeo to $\Delta(1)$. Hence it is an restriction of some automorphism of $Aut(\hat{C})$. The question is whether it holds in general, say $D$ is no longer simply connected but connected? In particular, given $f\in Aut(D)$, I can extend it uniquely to $Aut(\hat{C})$.

Q2. It seems that one cannot drop the condition that $D$ is connected. If $U_1,U_2$ are 2 disconnnected open set. So I expect $Aut(U_1\cup U_2)=Aut(U_1)\times Aut(U_2)$ and this might not be embedded as a subgroup of $Aut(\hat{C})$.

The reason I am asking this question is that for any finite extension $L$ over $Q$, the morphism $f:L\to C$ can be extended to $\tilde{f}:C\to C$. I am wonder whether this holds in analogy.

Comment: @reuns Yes. I would certainly hope so for unit disk for sure. If not simply connected, then I do not know.

Comment: So you meant $Aut(D)$ embeds into $ Aut(\hat{\mathbb{C}})$ with some biholomorphic map, that you should write as $Aut(D) \simeq H \le Aut(\hat{\mathbb{C}})$. For a given non-trivial subgroup $H$, what are the domains $U$ fixed by it ?

Comment: @reuns I have corrected it now.

Comment: I would start with : what are the domains $U$ fixed by given a non-trivial Möbius transformation ?

Comment: @reuns. So there are domains that are not fixed by any mobius transformations?